# ASP.NET Menu sitemap não funciona após alterar versao do framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, menu, iis-7, sitemap

Houve a necessidade de trocar uma aplicação de servidor, porém, o servidor novo funciona com o `IIS 7.0` e a aplicação que era desenvolvida em `.NET 3.5` foi alterada para .NET4.0. Quando a aplicação roda local em meu micro tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas quando publicada o menu `sitemap` para de funcionar.

Alguém sabe me dizer o motivo?

Segue o código `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!--Status-->
    <add key="SentToRepairStatus" value="W"/>
    <!--Planilha Excel Importação de Produtos Atendidos-->
    <!--Sheets-->
    <add key="SheetFlex" value="Flex"/>
    <add key="SheetIPGAcessories" value="Acessórios IPG"/>
    <add key="SheetPCs" value="PCs"/>
    <!--Sheets Columns-->
    <add key="SheetColumnPL" value="PL"/>
    <add key="SheetColumnProductNumber" value="Product Number"/>
    <add key="SheetColumnDescription" value="Description"/>
    <add key="SheetColumnServiceCenter" value="Service Center"/>
    <add key="SheetColumnServiceTypesAtendimento" value="Service Types de Atendimento"/>
    <add key="SheetColumnComments" value="Comments"/>
    <add key="SheetColumnChecked" value="Checked"/>
    <add key="SheetColumnPartNumber" value="Part Number"/>
    <add key="SheetColumnPNAtendimento" value="PN Atendimento"/>
    <!--IntegrationUser-->
    <add key="WSIntegrationUser" value="WS"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <!-- 
      Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
      symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
      affects performance, set this value to true only 
      during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Drawing.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <!--
      The <authentication> section enables configuration 
      of the security authentication mode used by 
      ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="eFlexAuth" loginUrl="Default.aspx" defaultUrl="Main\Main.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!--
      The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
      of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
      during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
      it enables developers to configure html error pages 
      to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
    -->
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="eFlexRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" cookieTimeout="30" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All" createPersistentCookie="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="eFlexRoleProvider" type="eFlex.Web.Providers.eFlexRoleProvider" applicationName="eFlex"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <siteMap defaultProvider="Menu-en-US" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="Menu-en-US" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Menu-en-US.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImage_axd"/>
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd"/>
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx"/>
      <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx"/>
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd"/>
      <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
      <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Sitemap.xml" path="*.xml" verb="*" type="MA.Umbraco.Web.SiteMapGenerator.SiteMapHttpHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <location path="Images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Main">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Styles">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Main/Main.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="PageError.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Receiving">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Receiving, Support, Administrator, Order"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="NFTK">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="NFTK, Support, Administrator, Order"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Invoice">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Invoice, Support, Administrator, Order"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Maintenance">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator, Support"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Order">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Order, Invoice, Support, Administrator"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="View">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="View, Support, Invoice, Administrator, NFTK"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Reports">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Reports, Invoice, NFTK, Order, Receiving, Support, View, Administrator"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="UserEmail.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="ChangePassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: O que seria parar de funcionar?